# Display Only Certain Category In a Custom Page Template

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, blog

I have a **Page** in Wordpress that is a **Blog Page Template**. Now my issue is that it displays ALL the posts. I only want it to display posts assigned to a certain **category**

How do I do that?

Here is my blog.php page: I guess you have to edit it here right?

```
/*
Template Name: Blog page
*/

$gogo_blog_text_no_posts = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_blog_text_no_posts', true);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$gogo_blog_text_no_posts.'&paged='.$paged); 
$postcount = 0;
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); $postcount++;

//the loop goes here

$wp_query= null;
$temp = $wp_query;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what `$gogo_blog_text_no_posts` is but you should be able to change this:

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$gogo_blog_text_no_posts.'&paged='.$paged);
```

to

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$gogo_blog_text_no_posts.'&paged='.$paged.'&cat=1');
```

See [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: thank you BandonRandon - How do I know which posts arev category 1 ('&cat=1')...I added that line and it now shows only the default categories(which came with the theme). How do I specify my own posts as category 1 or 2 etc?

Comment: Ok cool. Got it to work using: '&category_name=***yourcategory***'. One more thing. I want to make another page with a Blog Page Template, but for this page I only want to display another category, but since it will be using the same blog.php page, how do I specify another category for a new page?

Comment: You could either a) rename the template and change the category or b) use a conditional statement (http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to check the page slug around the `wp_query` although I recommend the first way.  Also if this solved your issue please mark it resolved.

Comment: Also in `cat=1` the `1` is that cat id which is always unique. You can get the id by using `get_cat_ID` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) The slug (what you did) works too as long as you don't change the name of the slug.

Comment: @DextrousDave Will you mark this as "solved?"